# How to trigger the click event of <lightning:fileUpload>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, fileupload

I want to display the `lightning:fileUpload` differently

After many tryouts with css hacks, I decided this is not good enough

My current approach is to create a different button, and upon clicking on it - trigger the click of the `lightning:fileUpload`

But I am failing to click the component - I have tried to get the component with aura:id and click it:

**MARKUP**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" description="Id of the current record" />
    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:upload" variant="border-filled" size="large" onclick="{!c.uploadFile}" title="upload file" />
    <lightning:fileUpload aura:id="fileUploader"
                          class="slds-hide"
                          multiple="false"
                          recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                          onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}"
                          title="Click to upload a file"/>
</aura:component>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
uploadFile: function(component, event, helper) {
    var fileUploader = component.find("fileUploader");
    fileUploader.click();
}
```

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to trigger the click event of the `lightning:fileUpload` component?

If not - is there a more elegant way to replace `lightning:fileUpload` component's button and all other visual stuff, and display a more nice simple button?

Comment: Have you tri d wrapping it in a div, with an onclick event?

Comment: No. But I need the click of the fileUpload component.  How would I trigger that?

Comment: What happens when you try? Nothing? An error?

Comment: @sfdcfox nothing happens. if I use chrom dev tools and click F10 on this line, I get inside the aura_prod.js into a catch. is there a way to get to the actual `input` html element and click it?

Comment: @ItaiShmida have you found a solution for this? I've tried the div wrapper like suggested too but then I can't access the child input element. I would like to try a different approach using the onchange event - any ideas?

Comment: @dangt85 I did not find any solution to trigger the click event of the lightning:fileUpload component. eventually I am using css hacks to display this component exactly the way I like on my page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not "satisfied" with the OOTB component, you are almost better off creating your own. You can view peter knowles [FileController.cls](https://gist.github.com/peterknolle/bb4b7ac63f67f66c32b0) Lightning component and style as needed. Otherwise, your only option will be to "overwrite" the current components CSS, and there is no "Clean" way to do this.

Here is a minimal CSS code sample (No scope) to achieve something similar to your icon only button alongside a few tips:

set the outermost element to:

```
visibility: hidden
```

and the innermost to

```
visibility: visible
```

then, you can set a width to your component and hide the overflow text (to keep the icon:

```
width: 30px;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
visibility: visible;
```

and set a margin to the primitive icon:

```
    margin-left: -Xpx;
```

And this should result in a small upload widget such as :

[image]

Comment: The downside of trying to roll your own `lightning:fileUpload` is, you'll be limited by the maximum Apex heap size. `lightning:fileUpload` can bypass that limit.